# Google Map at full height not adapting to window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set the google map to have a height of 85%. If the window is big enough it will have the proper size. But if the window is small it overlaps somehow.

Here some images

When window is big enough:
[image]

When window is smaller (no gray border at the bottom):
[image]

Some of the code. I use Bootstrap 3

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row full-height">
    <div class="col-md-12 full-height">
      <div class="map-container">
         {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, section, .mainpanel, .contentpanel { height: 100%; }

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}

.map-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I wish it would resize properly so it does not overlap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to look at the google maps api, specifically `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

Comment: The problem is that even if I refresh the page when the window is small it does not size correctly

Comment: Try `position: absolute;`. W3 school quotes >The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. So it would still be relative to the parent window but would make sure its 85% when it resize.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you are after, you either must use JavaScript to size/resize the map div or use [CSS positioning techniques](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [@Kay_N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386486/kay-n)'s answer did the trick for me.

TLDR

Add `position: absolute;` to map's div element to have it take the appropriate height of the viewport.